# Merging branch to master, ignoring changes in master

Tags: tortoisegit

I am new to using TortoiseGit, and after struggling with it I have a really messy repository now. I have this long Branch_4a... as the copy I am really working on. How can I make this Branch_4a.. as the master copy! I really don't care about any of the changes in the master branch I just want Branch_4a to be my  master branch. How can I do that?

[image: I want this to be the master branch]
[image]

Comment: `git checkout -B master Branch_4a`

Comment: Do you know how I can do this using tortoise git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this attached image as answer.

[image: TortoiseGit create branch]